# Managing web driver code separately

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Can you help me with this question.

I am working on a test automation framework and I want to keep my webdriver code separately and initiate from my test cases.

please help me in this. - Thanks

Comment: Can you elaborate? What is your need? It is unclear what you are asking for?

Comment: Sorry Guys - It was a general Question :) I wanted an approach where i can handle my webdriver code like storing my firefox driver, chrome driver, IE driver, managing cookies, maximize the browser in a location under the project and just use the drivers in my test case by just adding one line of code rather than writing all the webdriver code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go for the POM Model with Encapsulation . In the Example below I have created a Test Setup class which can then be used in all the test classes.

So this would be you TestSetup Class-

```
        using NUnit.Framework;
    using OpenQA.Selenium;
    using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
    using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
    using OpenQA.Selenium.IE;



    namespace dummy
    {
        [SetUpFixture]
        public class TestSetup
        {
            public static IWebDriver driver;   


            [OneTimeSetUp]
            public void testSetup()
            {

                if (driver == null)
                {
                    //Local Tests
                    driver = new FirefoxDriver();

                }
            }


            public static bool IsElementPresent(By by)
            {
                try
                {
                    driver.FindElement(by);
                    return true;
                }
                catch (NoSuchElementException)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            [OneTimeTearDown]
            public void TearDown()
            {
                driver.Quit();
            }

        }
    }
```

And Below can be you TestCase Class . Notice that you are just calling the test setup .So your test class will inherit all the functions from the Primary class-TestSetup

```
using System;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using NUnit.Framework;
using System.Threading;

namespace dummy
{
    [TestFixture]
    [Parallelizable]
    public class TESTCASE
    {        

        IWebDriver driver = TestSetup.driver;

        [Test] 

        public void siteVisit()
        {
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://google.com");
             Assert.IsTrue(String.Equals("Google, driver.Title));

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rahul..I will surely try this and let u know.

Answer (score 0):

Hi if i have understood it correctly then please go for POM (Page object Framework)

```
1.The main advantage of Page Object Model is that if the UI changes for any page, it don’t 
require us to change any tests, we just need to change only the code within the page objects 
(Only at one place).

2.Page Object model is writing all the functionalities / reusable components of a page that
we want to automate in a separate class.

3.As per google wiki Page object **"Within your web app’s UI there are areas that your tests 
interact with. A Page Object simply models these as objects within the test code. This 
reduces the amount of duplicated code and means that if the UI changes, the fix need only 
be applied in one place."**

Example : google home page

1.Say now if we consider our google home page as Home page.
2.For the above pages we will create class as HomePage.class.
3.In class we will identify and write reusable methods which are specific to Home page.
4.'google home page' which will have many options like Search, Sign In, +You, Images etc.
5.Now all functionalities that we want to automate should have reusable methods/components 
for each page.
6.as our main page is google page we can navigate to other pages by clicking on any link 
from the google page. When ever we are navigating to other page, we need to return that page 
object. Else Return the current page object as this action doesn't navigate to a other page 
represented by another Page Object.
```

**advantages.**

```
1.There is clean separation between test code and page specific code such as locators 
(or their use if you’re using a UI map) and layout.
2.There is single repository for the services or operations offered by the page rather than 
  having these services scattered through out the tests.
```

In both cases this allows any modifications required due to UI changes to all be made in one place.Click for more on [POM](https://www.3pillarglobal.com/insights/abstracting-selenium-tests-using-page-object-model)

Comment: Thanks Raj - I will try this and let u know.

Comment: yeah sure if you need help on POM please feel free to ask